# How to change colours within iframe loaded page

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

<iframe src="http://connectotravel.com/" height="100%" width="100%" id="frame">  </iframe>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.frameReady( function() {


);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is to change the background color within this iframe using jquery. Any help will do.

Comment: Unless your own site is also http://connectotravel.com/ you wont be able to, because of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with contents API of Jquery library

Just add this with in the script tag ( you please change the colour code with your desired colour number )

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#frame").contents().find("body").css("background-color", "#BADA55");
});
```

If this didnt work you can also try by finding html element itself

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
     $("#frame").contents().find("html").css("background-color", "#BADA55");
}
```

**References : -** 
[Iframe content access via jquery](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: i tried this, but there was no result, apparently you can't edit pages within iframe, if that page is not in your domain :( 
Thank you for the help tho :)

Comment: @user2845649 Aha Its not always , once if you load the content in your iframe then the content belongs to the client and he can do what ever he want manually ( using firebug or using javascript injections like the way you are trying ) we can'nt conclude that its not possible

Comment: IT also depends on the page , if the page some divs occupying the body and that has back ground then you wont see the back ground change in front so